# Speed up a program that calculate the average of the neighbors in a huge array

Tags: python, numpy, performance, numerical

I have a problem with the speed of my program. I want to calculate the average of four neighbors in a huge array. Here is a part of my code. Do you have any ideas how to change the last line? Or should I use another array?

```
for a in np.arange(100000):
    for x in np.arange(size):
        for y in np.arange(size):
            if unchangeableflag[x*size+y] == 0:
                vnew[x*size+y] = (v[(x+1)*size+y] + v[(x-1)*size+y] + v[x*size+y+1] + v[x*size+y-1]) / 4.0
```

Comment: Why the loop over `a`?  Would you like to achieve iterative convergence?

Comment: Maybe this is for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (am I right?)

Comment: @Sven Marnach This is an iterative process, yes.

Comment: The code you provided does 100000 times the same computation.  Are you assigning `v = vnew` after each itteration of the outermost loop?

Comment: @Alberteddu:  I think this is a better fit for StackOverflow than for Code Review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would not need the loop at all.  Assuming `v`, `vnew` and `unchangeableflag` are 1-d arrays with `size*size` entries, you can do

```
v = v.reshape(size, size)
vnew = vnew.reshape(size, size)
unchangeableflag = unchangeableflag.reshape(size, size)
average = v[1:-1, 2:]
average += v[1:-1, :-2] 
average += v[2:, 1:-1]
average += v[-2:, 1:-1]
average /= 4.0
vnew[1:-1, 1:-1][unchangeableflag[1:-1, 1:-1] == 0] = average
```

But what are you actually trying to achieve?  This looks suspiciously like you could get away with some application of the discrete Laplacian.

(Note that this assumes that `v` contains floating point numbers.  If the `dtype` of `v´ is sime integral type, you need a slight modification.)

Comment: I think that i loose always the outermost line. Right?

Comment: @kame: Your own code has somewhat undefined behaviour on the boundaries.  If you define what should be done on the boundaries, it can of course be incorporated.

Comment: @kame - The numpy and scipy convolve functions allow some different approaches to how the boundaries are treated.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using SciPy's [convolution filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.8.x/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve) or the [generic_filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter). This is still computationally intensive, but way faster than looping. Normally, when doing this type of averaging, the central element is also included. Note that these solutions also apply to multi-dimensional arrays.

```
from scipy import ndimage
footprint = scipy.array([[0,0.25,0],[0.25,0,0.25],[0,0.25,0]])
filtered_array = scipy.convolve(array, footprint)
```

OR

```
from scipy import ndimage
def myfunction(window):
    return (window[0,1] + window[1,0] + window[1,2] + window[2,1]) / 4
filtered_array = scipy.generic_filter(array, myfunction, size=3)
```

Comment: These solutions are concise, but not fastest.  Especially the second solution is quite slow.  In the first solution, you probably want to use `ndimage.convolve()` instead of `scipy.convolve`, since the latter is for 1d arrays only.  Furthermore, both solution disregard the mysterious `unchangeableflag` in the original post.

Comment: convolve1d is for 1d arrays, convolve is the multi-dimentional version. Because of the way I import ndimage, I don't think I need to specify scipy.ndimage.convolve. I'm less concerned with keeping and fixing the original code than with providing an example of a simpler and more effective alternative...

Comment: `scipy.convolve` and `scipy.ndimage.convolve` are _not_ the same function at all!!  Anything in the "bare" `scipy` namespace is just there for historical reasons (i.e. they're just numpy functions, though some have different defaults).  _All_ of scipy's functionality is in the other namespaces such as `scipy.ndimage`, `scipy.special`, `scipy.signal`, etc.  Other than that, though, I agree, this can certainly be done with a convolution.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded a bit harsh... I just wanted to make the difference clear... The fact that `import scipy` doesn't actually do anything (other than importing `numpy`) is confusing to a lot of people at first (Or it was to me for quite awhile, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure but you can remove some invariant.

```
for a in np.arange(100000):
    for x in np.arange(size):
        for y in np.arange(size):
            t = x*size+y
            if unchangeableflag[t] == 0:
                vnew[t] = (v[t+size] + v[t-size] + v[t+1] + v[t-1]) / 4.0
```

Comment: Instead of dividing by 4, you could use shift the bits to the right twice:

vnet[t] = (v[t+size] + v[t-size] + v[t+1] + v[t-1]);
vnet[t] >>= 2;

Comment: @tdobek What? Can you explain this?

Comment: @tdobek: These are floating point computations.  Shifting won't work (nor would it be any faster even if it did).

Comment: @Sven Marnach: In this case my idea is void. And it's Python so yeah shifting bits won't necessarily help. Sorry!