# Sliding window using as_strided function in numpy?

Tags: image-processing, numpy, computer-vision, scipy

As I get to implement a sliding window using python to detect objects in still images, I get to know the nice function:

```
numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
```

So I tried to achieve a general rule to avoid mistakes I may fail in while changing the size of the sliding windows I need. Finally I got this representation:

```
all_windows = as_strided(x,((x.shape[0] - xsize)/xstep ,(x.shape[1] - ysize)/ystep ,xsize,ysize), (x.strides[0]*xstep,x.strides[1]*ystep,x.strides[0],x.strides[1])
```

which results in a 4 dim matrix. The first two represents the number of windows on the x and y axis of the image. and the others represent the size of the window (xsize,ysize)

and the `step` represents the displacement from between two consecutive windows.

This representation works fine if I choose a squared sliding windows. but still I have a problem in getting this to work for windows of e.x. (128,64), where I get usually unrelated data to the image.

What is wrong my code. Any ideas? and if there is a better way to get a sliding windows nice and neat in python for image processing?

Thanks

Comment: Since you were looking for a template matching algorithms, [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41379596/3293881) might be worth a look that uses strides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the answers to this question: [Using strides for an efficient moving average filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936620/using-strides-for-an-efficient-moving-average-filter). Basically strides are not a great option, although they work.

Comment: So is there any better alternative that is fast and yet neat for extracting sliding windows at different scales for the sake of detection and template matching algorithms ??

Comment: I need to extract such subwindows where to get some HOG features over the window, and classify this instance against already trained classifier to check if it is a subwindow I am concerned about or not.

Comment: For the argument sake, yes something similar, regarding the HOG, I have previously implemented it using nested loops to extract its cells histogram, I thought that the stride tricks would save some performance and eliminate the usage of 2 loops that is really expensive in this context using a language like python or matlab.

Comment: @JustInTime hi, were you able to solve your problem? I have some more questions regarding the sliding window approach, is it possible to contact you?

Comment: Take a look at [view_as_windows](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.10.x/api/skimage.util.html#view-as-windows) Hope it will help.

Answer (score 4):

There is an issue in your code. Actually this code work good for 2D and no reason to use multi dimensional version ([Using strides for an efficient moving average filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936620/using-strides-for-an-efficient-moving-average-filter)). Below is a fixed version:

```
A = np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10))
print A
all_windows = as_strided(A, ((A.shape[0] - xsize + 1) / xstep, (A.shape[1] - ysize + 1) / ystep, xsize, ysize),
      (A.strides[0] * xstep, A.strides[1] * ystep, A.strides[0], A.strides[1]))
print all_windows
```

Answer (score 1):

For posteriority:

This is implemented in scikit-learn in the function `sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches`.

Comment: I believe this method makes a copy from the original image for the patches, and it seems the striding method is intended specifically to avoid doing that.

Comment: As an alternative, see skimage.util.view_as_windows (http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows)

Comment: @AlexKlibisz `extract_patches` uses strides in the most general form (works for all `ndarray`s of arbitrary dimension and you can extract arbitrarily shaped patches at arbitrary steps). `extract_patches_2d` uses this function, but calls a reshape and thus induces a copy (this is wanted for the 2D case). [full disclosure: I wrote `extract_patches`]

Comment: It looks like the `skimage` function implements the exact same functionality.  For completeness, here is the [source of `extract_patches`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.18.X/sklearn/feature_extraction/image.py#L242)

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I mistakenly used `extract_patches_2d` instead of `extract_patches`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar use-case where I needed to create sliding windows over a batch of multi-channel images and ended up coming up with the below function. [I've written a more in-depth blog post covering this in regards to manually creating a Convolution layer](https://blog.ca.meron.dev/Vectorized-CNN/). This function implements the sliding windows and also includes dilating or adding padding to the input array.

The function takes as input:

`input - Size of (Batch, Channel, Height, Width)
output_size - Depends on usage, comments below.
kernel_size - size of the sliding window you wish to create (square)
padding - amount of 0-padding added to the outside of the (H,W) dimensions
stride - stride the sliding window should take over the inputs
dilate - amount to spread the cells of the input. This adds 0-filled rows/cols between elements`

Typically, when performing forward convolution, you do not need to perform dilation so your output size can be found be using the following formula (replace x with input dimension):

`(x - kernel_size + 2 * padding) // stride + 1`

When performing the backwards pass of convolution with this function, use a stride of 1 and set your output_size to the size of your forward pass's x-input

Sample code with an example of using this function can be found [at this link](https://github.com/cameronwhite08/vectorized_convolution).

```
def getWindows(input, output_size, kernel_size, padding=0, stride=1, dilate=0):
    working_input = input
    working_pad = padding
    # dilate the input if necessary
    if dilate != 0:
        working_input = np.insert(working_input, range(1, input.shape[2]), 0, axis=2)
        working_input = np.insert(working_input, range(1, input.shape[3]), 0, axis=3)

    # pad the input if necessary
    if working_pad != 0:
        working_input = np.pad(working_input, pad_width=((0,), (0,), (working_pad,), (working_pad,)), mode='constant', constant_values=(0.,))

    in_b, in_c, out_h, out_w = output_size
    out_b, out_c, _, _ = input.shape
    batch_str, channel_str, kern_h_str, kern_w_str = working_input.strides

    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        working_input,
        (out_b, out_c, out_h, out_w, kernel_size, kernel_size),
        (batch_str, channel_str, stride * kern_h_str, stride * kern_w_str, kern_h_str, kern_w_str)
    )
```