# Compute mean squared, absolute deviation and custom similarity measure - Python/NumPy

Tags: python, image, numpy, similarity, convolution

I have a large image as an 2D array (let's assume that it is a 500 by 1000 pixels gray scale image). And I have one small image (let's say is it 15 by 15 pixels). I would like to slide the small image over the large one and for a given position of the small image I would like to calculate a measure of similarity between the small image and the underling part of the big image.

**I would like to be flexible in choosing a measure of similarity. For example I might want to calculate mean squared deviation or mean absolute deviation or something else (just some operation that takes two matrices of the same size and returns a real number).**

The result should be a 2D array. I want to do this operation efficiently (which means that I want to avoid loops).

As a measure of similarity I plan to use the square deviations between the colors of the two images. However, as I have mentioned, it would be nice if I can change the measure (for example to use correlation between the colors).

Is there a function in numpy that can do it?

Comment: Seems relevant - [`How can I check if one two-dimensional NumPy array contains a specific pattern of values inside it?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531377/how-can-i-check-if-one-two-dimensional-numpy-array-contains-a-specific-pattern-o).

Comment: Are you open to using OpenCV? It seems to have built-ins for that - http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html.

Comment: Your requirements of "loopless" and "2D array" are essentially irreconcilable.  You can use `skimage.util.view_as_windows` to get a 3 or 4D array (depending on whether to split the RBG values) as in Divakar's solution, and then broadcast your comparison function.  Or you can loop (which could conceivably be faster for an efficient search function, but that will be entirely dependent on your measure of similarity, and thus not generalize-able)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Import modules

To start off, let's import all the relevant modules/functions that would be used across the various approaches listed in this post -

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows
from skimage.feature import match_template
import cv2
from cv2 import matchTemplate as cv2m
from scipy.ndimage.filters import uniform_filter as unif2d
from scipy.signal import convolve2d as conv2
```

---

### A. Views based approach for MAD, MSD

**Skimage based approaches for computing `mean absolute deviation` :**

Using scikit-image for getting [`slided 4D array of views`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) and then [`np.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) for the average calculations -

```
def skimage_views_MAD_v1(img, tmpl):
    return np.abs(view_as_windows(img, tmpl.shape) - tmpl).mean(axis=(2,3))
```

Using scikit-image for getting slided 4D array of views and then [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for the squared-average calculations -

```
def skimage_views_MAD_v2(img, tmpl):
    subs = np.abs(view_as_windows(img, tmpl.shape) - tmpl)
    return np.einsum('ijkl->ij',subs)/float(tmpl.size)
```

---

**Skimage based approaches for computing `mean squared deviation` :**

Using the similar techniques, we would have two approaches for `mean squared deviation` -

```
def skimage_views_MSD_v1(img, tmpl):
    return ((view_as_windows(img, tmpl.shape) - tmpl)**2).mean(axis=(2,3))

def skimage_views_MSD_v2(img, tmpl):
    subs = view_as_windows(img, tmpl.shape) - tmpl
    return np.einsum('ijkl,ijkl->ij',subs, subs)/float(tmpl.size)
```

---

### B. Convolution based approach for MSD

**Convolution based approaches for computing `mean squared deviations` :**

`Convolution` could be used to used to compute mean squared deviations in a bit of tweaked way. For the case of sum of squared deviations, within each window we are performing elementwise subtractions and then squaring each subtraction and then summing up all those.

Let's consider a 1D example for a closer look -

```
a : [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8] # Image array
b : [b1, b2, b3]                     # Template array
```

For the first window operation, we would have :

```
(a1-b1)**2 + (a2-b2)**2 + (a3-b3)**2
```

Let's use `(a-b)**2` formula :

```
(a - b)**2 = a**2 - 2*a*b +b**2
```

Thus, we would have for the first window :

```
(a1**2 - 2*a1*b1 +b1**2) + (a2**2 - 2*a2*b2 +b2**2) + (a3**2 - 2*a3*b3 +b3**2)
```

Similarly, for the second window :

```
(a2**2 - 2*a2*b1 +b1**2) + (a3**2 - 2*a3*b2 +b2**2) + (a4**2 - 2*a4*b3 +b3**2)
```

and so on.

So, we have three parts to these computations -

- Squaring of a's and summing of those in sliding windows.
- Squaring of b's and summing of those. This stays the same among all windows.
- Final piece of puzzle is : `(2*a1*b1, 2*a2*b2, 2*a3*b3)`, `(2*a2*b1, 2*a3*b2, 2*a4*b3)` and so on for the first, second and so on windows. This could be computed by a `2D` convolution with `a` and flipped version of `b` as per the definition of [`convolution`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) that runs the kernel from the other direction in a sliding and computes elementwise multiplication and sums elements within each window and hence the flipped needed here.

Extending these ideas to `2D` case and using `Scipy's convolve2d` and `uniform_filter`, we would have two more approaches to compute `mean squared deviations`, like so -

```
def convolution_MSD(img, tmpl):
    n = tmpl.shape[0]
    sums = conv2(img**2,np.ones((n,n)),'valid')
    out = sums + (tmpl**2).sum() -2*conv2(img,tmpl[::-1,::-1],'valid')
    return out/(n*n)

def uniform_filter_MSD(img, tmpl):
    n = tmpl.shape[0]
    hWSZ = (n-1)//2
    sums = unif2d(img.astype(float)**2,size=(n,n))[hWSZ:-hWSZ,hWSZ:-hWSZ]
    out = sums + (tmpl**2).mean() -2*conv2(img,tmpl[::-1,::-1],'valid')/float(n*n)
    return out
```

---

### C. Skimage based approach for NCC

**Skimage based approaches for computing `normalized cross-correlation` :**

```
def skimage_match_template(img, tmpl):
    return match_template(img, tmpl)
```

Please note that, since these are cross-correlation values, the closeness between image and template would be characterized by a high output value.

---

### D. OpenCV based approach for various similarity measures

OpenCV offers various [`template-matching`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) methods of classifying templates -

```
def opencv_generic(img, tmpl, method_string ='SQDIFF'):
    # Methods : 
    # 'CCOEFF' : Correlation coefficient
    # 'CCOEFF_NORMED' : Correlation coefficient normalized
    # 'CCORR' : Cross-correlation
    # 'CCORR_NORMED' : Cross-correlation normalized
    # 'SQDIFF' : Squared differences
    # 'SQDIFF_NORMED' : Squared differences normalized

    method = eval('cv2.TM_' + method_string)
    return cv2m(img.astype('uint8'),tmpl.astype('uint8'),method)
```

---

### E. Views based approach : Custom function

We could use `4D` views as shown earlier in this post and perform the custom similarity measures as NumPy ufuncs along the last two axes.

Thus, we get the sliding windows as a 4D array as used previously, like so -

```
img_4D = view_as_windows(img, tmpl.shape)
```

Please note that being a view into the input image, it won't cost anymore on memory. But the later operations would make copy depending on those operations themselves. A comparison operation would result in much lesser memory footprint (8 times lesser on Linux to be exact).

Then, we perform the intended operation between `img_4D` and `tmpl`, which in a linearly mapped operation would result in another 4D array following [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Let's call it `img_sub`. Next up, most probably, we would have some reduction operation to give us a `2D` output. Again, in most cases, one of the [`NumPy ufuncs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) could be used here. We need to use this ufunc along the last two axes on `img_sub`. Again, many ufuncs allow us to work on more than one axis at a time. For example, earlier we used `mean` computation along last two axes in one go. Otherwise, we need to operate along those two axes one after another.

**Example**

As an example on how to use let's consider a custom function :

```
mean((img_W**tmpl)*tmpl - 2*img*tmpl**2)
```

Here, we have `img_W` as the sliding window from `img` and `tmpl` as usual is the template that is slided across the height and width of `img`.

Implemented with two nested loops, we would have :

```
def func1(a,b):
    m1,n1 = a.shape
    m2,n2 = b.shape
    mo,no = m1-m2+1, n1-n2+1
    out = np.empty((mo,no))
    for i in range(mo):
        for j in range(no):
            out[i,j] = ((a[i:i+m2,j:j+n2]**2)*b - 2*a[i:i+m2,j:j+n2]*(b**2)).mean()
    return out
```

Now, using `view_as_windows`, we would have a vectorized solution :

```
def func2(a,b):
    a4D = view_as_windows(img, tmpl.shape)
    return ((a4D**2)*b - 2*a4D*(b**2)).mean(axis=(2,3))
```

Runtime test -

```
In [89]: # Sample image(a) and template(b)
    ...: a = np.random.randint(4,9,(50,100))
    ...: b = np.random.randint(2,9,(15,15))
    ...: 

In [90]: %timeit func1(a,b)
1 loops, best of 3: 147 ms per loop

In [91]: %timeit func2(a,b)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.8 ms per loop
```

---

### Benchmarking : Mean squared deviation

Decent sized datasets :

```
In [94]: # Inputs
    ...: img = np.random.randint(0,255,(50,100))
    ...: tmpl = np.random.randint(0,255,(15,15))
    ...: 

In [95]: out1 = skimage_views_MSD_v1(img, tmpl)
    ...: out2 = skimage_views_MSD_v2(img, tmpl)
    ...: out3 = convolution_MSD(img, tmpl)
    ...: out4 = uniform_filter_MSD(img, tmpl)
    ...: out5 = opencv_generic(img, tmpl, 'SQDIFF')/tmpl.size
    ...: 
    ...: print np.allclose(out1, out2)
    ...: print np.allclose(out1, out3)
    ...: print np.allclose(out1, out4)
    ...: print np.allclose(out1, out5)
    ...: 
True
True
True
True

In [96]: %timeit skimage_views_MSD_v1(img, tmpl)
    ...: %timeit skimage_views_MSD_v2(img, tmpl)
    ...: %timeit convolution_MSD(img, tmpl)
    ...: %timeit uniform_filter_MSD(img, tmpl)
    ...: %timeit opencv_generic(img, tmpl, 'SQDIFF')/tmpl.size
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 8.49 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.87 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.96 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.25 ms per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 201 µs per loop
```

For bigger datasizes, depending on the system RAM available, we might have to fall back to methods other than `views` method that leaves noticeable memory footprint.

Let's test out on bigger datasizes with the remaining approaches -

```
In [97]: # Inputs
    ...: img = np.random.randint(0,255,(500,1000))
    ...: tmpl = np.random.randint(0,255,(15,15))
    ...: 

In [98]: %timeit convolution_MSD(img, tmpl)
    ...: %timeit uniform_filter_MSD(img, tmpl)
    ...: %timeit opencv_generic(img, tmpl, 'SQDIFF')/tmpl.size
    ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 910 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 483 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 16.1 ms per loop
```

---

### Summary

- When working with known similarity measures , i.e. one of the six methods listed with OpenCV based template matching method and if we have access to OpenCV, that would be the best one.
- Without OpenCV, for a special case like mean squared deviation, we could make use of convolution to have decently efficient approaches.
- For generic/custom functions and with decent sized datasizes, we could look into `4D` views to have efficient vectorized solutions. For large datasizes, we might want to use one loop and use `3D` views instead of `4D` with the intention of reducing memory footprint. For really large ones, you might have to fall back to two nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to a **Cross Correlation** operation?

However, if you strictly want to check similarity with a squared deviation, you can use template matching in skimage, which uses a faster implementation of cross correlation. Example here : http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_template.html

Otherwise, you can use correlate2d to achieve this as follows : 
1. Perform a cross correlation on a zero-mean signal (meaning both signals/images should be centered about zero)
2. Check for local maxima  scipy.signal.argrelmax or (if you think there would only be a single match) look for a global maxima using np.argmax

Here is an example (lifted off from the documentation), you can replace np.argmax with signal.argrelmax if necessary for your purpose

```
from scipy import signal
from scipy import misc
lena = misc.lena() - misc.lena().mean()
template = np.copy(lena[235:295, 310:370]) # right eye
template -= template.mean()
lena = lena + np.random.randn(*lena.shape) * 50 # add noise
corr = signal.correlate2d(lena, template, boundary='symm', mode='same')
y, x = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(corr), corr.shape) # find the match
```

Source :

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate2d.html

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelmax.html#scipy.signal.argrelmax

Comment: but cross correlation is not the same as squared deviations.

Comment: Since you were looking for measures of similarity, I thought this would help. I will edit my answer to add for what you had asked.