# Most efficient way to implement rolling windows on NumPy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Given some small window, I'm trying to find the most similar window within a long sequence. I initially used **SciPy** correlation filter, which was pretty fast (less than a second for windows of length 10k and a sequence of length 600k) but did not actually land on the most similar windows.

Now I'm using a for-loop to find the window with the least MSE, but the code is painfully slow!

```py
min_mse = np.inf
min_mse_idx = None
for i in range(len(training_data) - self.window_size):
  real_window = training_data[i:i+self.window_size]
  mse = np.mean(np.square(window - real_window))
  if mse < min_mse:
    min_mse = mse
    min_mse_idx = i
```

Does NumPy, SciPy, or any other Python library provide a more efficient way of solving this problem? The sequence is a NumPy array of shape `(600000, 16)` and the windows are usually `(10000, 16)`.

Comment: Seems very relevant -  [`Compute mean squared, absolute deviation and custom similarity measure - Python/NumPy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330517/compute-mean-squared-absolute-deviation-and-custom-similarity-measure-python).

Comment: The solutions offered in that question work best for images and not long sequences.

Comment: The only difference I see is that you won't be traversing along the width. So, the math stays the same, just the number of axes would be one less.