# Reasoning about consecutive data points without using iteration

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, spc

I am doing [SPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_process_control) analysis using [numpy](https://numpy.org/)/[pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

Part of this is checking data series against the [Nelson rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson_rules) and the [Western Electric rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Electric_rules).

For instance (rule 2 from the Nelson rules): Check if nine (or more) points in a row are on the same side of the mean.

Now I could simply implement checking a rule like this by iterating over the array.

- But before I do that, I'm checking here on SO if numpy/pandas has a way to do this without iteration?
- In any case: What is the "numpy-ic" way to implement a check like the one described above?

Comment: You could try stride tricks to get your moving slices. A google search should get you started (with other links to [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936620/using-strides-for-an-efficient-moving-average-filter), BTW)

Comment: Thanks everyone for their suggestions. I will try the different approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, you may want to try using some stride tricks.

- First, let's make an array of the size of your anomalies: we can put it as `np.int8` to save some space

  ```
  anomalies = x - x.mean()
  signs = np.sign(anomalies).astype(np.int8)
  ```
- Now for the strides. If you want to consider `N` consecutive points, you'll use

  ```
  from np.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
  strided = as_strided(signs, 
                       strides=(signs.itemsize,signs.itemsize), 
                       shape=(signs.shape,N))
  ```

  That gives us a `(x.size, N)` rollin array: the first row is `x[0:N]`, the second `x[1:N+1]`... Of course, the last `N-1` rows will be meaningless, so from now on we'll use

  ```
  strided = strided[:-N+1]
  ```
- Let's sum along the rows

  ```
  consecutives = strided.sum(axis=-1)
  ```

  That gives us an array of size `(x.size-N+1)` of values between `-N` and `+N`: we just have to find where the absolute values are `N`:

  ```
  (indices,) = np.nonzero(consecutives == N)
  ```

  `indices` is the array of the indices `i` of your array `x` for which the values `x[i:i+N]` are on the same side of the mean...

Example with `x=np.random.rand(10)` and `N=3`

```
>>> x = array([ 0.57016436,  0.79360943,  0.89535982,  0.83632245,  0.31046202,
            0.91398363,  0.62358298,  0.72148491,  0.99311681,  0.94852957])
>>> signs = np.sign(x-x.mean()).astype(np.int8)
array([-1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1], dtype=int8)
>>> strided = as_strided(signs,strides=(1,1),shape=(signs.size,3))
array([[  -1,    1,    1],
       [   1,    1,    1],
       [   1,    1,   -1],
       [   1,   -1,    1],
       [  -1,    1,   -1],
       [   1,   -1,   -1],
       [  -1,   -1,    1],
       [  -1,    1,    1],
       [   1,    1, -106],
       [   1, -106,  -44]], dtype=int8)
>>> consecutive=strided[:-N+1].sum(axis=-1)
array([ 1,  3,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1])
>>> np.nonzero(np.abs(consecutive)==N)
(array([1]),)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(100)
f = np.sign(x - x.mean())
c = np.cumsum(f)
d = c[9:] - c[:-9]
print np.max(d), np.min(d)
```

if np.max(d) == 9 or np.min(d) == -9 then there are nine (or more) points in a row are on the same side of the mean.

Or you can use following code to calculate the length of every row:

```
np.diff(np.where(np.diff(np.r_[-2,f,-2]))[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Given `data` and minimal `length`, you could check, whether the array

```
np.diff(np.cumsum(np.sign(data - np.mean(data))), length)
```

contains zero.

Answer (score 1):

another possibility: use correlate or convolve

```
>>> a = np.random.randn(50)
>>> b = (a - a.mean()) > 0
>>> b.astype(int)
array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
       1, 1, 1, 1])

>>> c = np.correlate(b, np.ones(3), mode='valid')
>>> c
array([ 2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  2.,  2.,
        1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  2.,  2.,
        2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,
        0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.])

>>> c.max() == 3
True
>>> c.min() == 0
True
```

It will be slower than HYRY cumsum version.

aside: there is a runstest in statsmodels for testing similar runs