# Sliding window for splitting a ndarray into smaller overlapping ndarrays

Tags: python, numpy, sliding-window

I am currently working out a method in which I can split a `numpy.ndarray` 
into a given number of sub-arrays, as long the number is less than the the axis which the window moves along.

#### Example:

Given an `numpy.ndarray` with shape `(15, 40, 3)` I want to divide in to 36 equal sized sub-arrays.  Overlap is allowed, since in most cases the length of the array and the number of sub-arrays not be evenly divisible.

Each sub-array has to have `(15, ?, 3)` as shape, in which `?` is the axis in which the sliding window moves. Overlapping is allowed.

How can I do that? `numpy.splits` requires items to be equally divisible and also does not allow overlap.

Expected output: 
Given a numpy.ndarray of shape (5,3), I want to extract 2 numpy.ndarrays of shape (5,2), with an sliding window moving axis = 1. it will always be this axis.

I don't want explicitly want set how much overlap there should be between both numpy.ndarrays, but only the number of ndarrays that there should be extracted..

So in this case, should each sub numpy.ndarray be placed like this:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split array into equal sized windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313706/split-array-into-equal-sized-windows)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sliding window in numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722324/sliding-window-in-numpy)

Comment: @aryamccarthy I am not sure i understand the solution.. where is the axis defined?

Comment: and @umutto ...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Added an example.. Didn't a code example.. Made an image of how i hope it would work..

Comment: Closest duplicate I could find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936620/using-strides-for-an-efficient-moving-average-filter?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The problem is underdefined. Consider an array of size 20 that you want to divide in 5 subarrays. You have three options (sub-array length l, overlay o): [l=8, o=5], [l=12, o=10], [l=16, o=15]. You will need to specify either array length or overlap, or a rule by which to select either.

Answer (score 1):

An implementation of what is being seemed can possibly be found here:

https://popi.ucdavis.edu/~travc/tmp/dev/racc/sliding_window.py