# NumPy: Convert and reshape 1D array to 2D array with zeros?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

How can I convert and reshape the following list to the 2D array with zeros?

```
# original list 
[1, 0.96, 0.92, 0.88]

# 2D Array
[[1     0     0     0   ]
 [0.96  1     0     0   ]
 [0.92  0.96  1     0   ]
 [0.88  0.92  0.96  1   ]]
```

Comment: Would you please explain a bit? converting 1D to 2D is not a big deal but the output you want points something.

Comment: Is the floating values in a 2D array need to follow some rules?

Comment: I want to use the 2d array as a dot product with another array to measure decay. No rule, just that the floating values need to be upto 2 decimal points.

Comment: @M.Innat The rule is quite obvious.. the 1D vector is repeated in each column with a shift by one down in every column cropping the last value. Have you tried with a for loop at least to show the process and then ask for a vectorized implementation?

Comment: For loop will be slow, so checking if there is some funky way to do so in NumPy itself.

Comment: @Shantanu Did either of the posted solutions work?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a funky vectorized way. We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windowed views and solve it.

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

# a is input array (convert to array with np.array() is input is list)
p = np.r_[a[::-1], np.zeros(len(a)-1, dtype=a.dtype)]
out = view_as_windows(p,len(a))[::-1]
```

Alternatively, keep it native to NumPy -

```
m = len(a)
n = p.strides[0]
out = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(p[m-1:], shape=(m,m), strides=(-n,n))
```

Comment: Interesting, really funky ;)

Answer (score 2):

The correct implementation with a `for` loop is:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1, 0.96, 0.92, 0.88])
B = np.zeros((A.shape[0], A.shape[0]))

for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    B[i:, i] = A[:A.shape[0]-i]
```

There should be a way to vectorize this and to get rid of the for loop for efficiency.. Anyone has an idea?

I found this SO post which is relatively similar and has a bunch of vectorized implementations: [Sliding window of M-by-N shape numpy.ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722324/sliding-window-of-m-by-n-shape-numpy-ndarray)

Comment: I found that `view_as_windows` (`1.42 s`) is much slower than your solution, for loop (`100 ms`).

Comment: @M.Innat That's not possible. Check again? Unless you are benchmarking on the 4 elements data?

Comment: @M.Innat That completely depends on the size of the data array. For a 4x4 array, a for loop is not that slow, but if you increase the size, the vectorized implementation will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Following works for you:

```
import numpy as np 

arr = np.array([1, 0.96, 0.92, 0.88])

arr_cp = np.zeros((arr.shape[0], arr.shape[0]))

for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
  arr_cp[i][:i+1] = np.flip(arr[:i+1])

print(arr_cp)
```

Output:

> ```
> [[1.   0.   0.   0.  ]
>  [0.96 1.   0.   0.  ]
>  [0.92 0.96 1.   0.  ]
>  [0.88 0.92 0.96 1.  ]]
> ```