# How to combine successive rows with an increasing overlap between them (just like a rolling window)?

Tags: python, pandas, data-augmentation

I am currently starting to learn Pandas and struggling to do a task with it. What I am trying to do is to augment the data stored in a dataframe by combining two succesive rows with an increasing overlap between them. Just like a rolling window.

I believe the question can exemplified with this small dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

which gives:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8
2   9   10  11  12
```

With it, what I want to accomplish but I don't know how to, is a dataframe like the next one:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1   2   3   4
1   2   3   4   5
2   3   4   5   6
3   4   5   6   7
4   5   6   7   8
5   6   7   8   9
6   7   8   9   10
7   8   9   10  11
8   9   10  11  12
```

As if we were using multiple rolling windows between each pair of the initial dataframe. Note that I am not using this specific dataframe (the values are not  really ordered like 1,2,3,4...).  What I am using is a general dataframe imported from a csv.

Is this possible?, thanks in advance!

---

**Edit**

Thanks to all the responses. Both answers given by anky and Shubham Sharma work perfect. Here are the results obtained by using both of them with my real dataframe:

**Initial dataframe**
[image]

**After adding multiple rolling windows as my question needed**
[image]

Comment: My answer below addresses the specific case of building the dataframe you are asking for. If the question is about the more general problem of taking a list and turning into a matrix of strided view then @anky 's solution is probably a better starting point. In that case, there is probably some numpy trick available to move from a list comprehension based solution to a faster one based on manipulating arrays.

Comment: Yes, my question is for a general dataframe, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Numpy 1.2 provies a sliding window function for exactly this:
https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be not as elegant, but try:

```
def fun(dataframe,n):
    l = dataframe.stack().tolist()
    return (pd.DataFrame([l[e:e+n] for e,i in enumerate(l)],
        columns=dataframe.columns).dropna().astype(dataframe.dtypes))
```

---

```
fun(df,df.shape[1])

   A   B   C   D
0  1   2   3   4
1  2   3   4   5
2  3   4   5   6
3  4   5   6   7
4  5   6   7   8
5  6   7   8   9
6  7   8   9  10
7  8   9  10  11
8  9  10  11  12
```

Comment: Thanks @anky, I tried it but I got an error because ```n``` is not defined. Does it represent the number of columns?

Comment: @JavierTG my bad, I missed adding that parameter, edited the answer. check now? Yes it is the no. of columns

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect :)

Comment: This answer to another question has a vectorized solution which may (or may not) be important depending on the size of your data.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42258242/938530

Comment: @GuillemB thanks for linking to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try `rolling` with `numpy`:

```
def rolling(a, w=4):
    s = a.strides[-1]
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, (len(a)-w+1, w), (s, s))

pd.DataFrame(rolling(df.values.reshape(-1)), columns=df.columns)
```

---

```
   A   B   C   D
0  1   2   3   4
1  2   3   4   5
2  3   4   5   6
3  4   5   6   7
4  5   6   7   8
5  6   7   8   9
6  7   8   9  10
7  8   9  10  11
8  9  10  11  12
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham Sharma, but I believe this answer doesn't hold for a general dataframe imported from a csv. As commented with GuillemB I think this is because of my small example provided in the question (sorry about the confusion).

Comment: @JavierTG What do you mean by `general dataframe` can you please elaborate?

Comment: My bad, that works also perfect. Sorry about my previous comment, I thought this answer was like the one provided by GuillemB, Thaks again for it!

Answer (score 1):

You can do all the weight lifting with numpy and then drop the resulting matrix into a dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n_columns = 4
n_rows = 9

aux = np.tile(
    np.arange(1, n_columns+1),  # base row
    (n_rows, 1)  # replicate it as many times as needed
)

# use broadcasting to add a per row offset to each row
aux = aux + np.arange(n_rows)[:, np.newaxis]

# put everything into a dataframe
pd.DataFrame(aux)
```

Comment: Thanks @GuillemB, but the dataframe is imported from a csv with ton of data and the values are not ordered like 1, 2, 3, 4... as in the small example I provided (sorry about the confusion), So I believe this answer does not hold for a more general dataframe. I am going to update the question to make it clearer.