# Matching arrays of different shape in python numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shapes, matching

I have a big 2d bitewise array (0s and 1s only) and a small one (3x3).

I want to see where the big array matches the small one, i.e. `i`, `j` for which

```
big_array[i-1:i+2, j-1:j+2] == small_array
```

There could be more than one `(i,j)` that satisfies the condition. How do I do this without writing a double nested `i`, `j` loop?

Comment: I adapted this answer to my case. stride_tricks is very fast.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936620/using-strides-for-an-efficient-moving-average-filter

Answer (score 2):

I hope, this code is what you need:

```
import numpy as np

big_array = np.array(...)
small_array = np.array(...)

for (i, j), _ in np.ndenumerate(big_array[:-2, :-2]):
    if (big_array[i:i+3, j:j+3] == small_array).all():
        print (i, j)
```