# Sliding window on an image to calculate variance of pixels in that window

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to build a function that uses sliding window over and image and calculates the variance of pixels in the window and returns a bounding box where there is the most variance observed.

I'm new to coding and I've tried solutions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936620/using-strides-for-an-efficient-moving-average-filter) but I don't know how to input image in that instead of array.

I'm on a deadline here and been trying this since a while so any help is much appreciated . TIA

Edit: Also, if someone could help me with how to call the [rolling_window_lastaxis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936620/using-strides-for-an-efficient-moving-average-filter) function and modify it to what I'm trying to do then it would mean a lot.

Comment: check the tutorial in pyimagesearch

Comment: Yes, I did that too. It generates multiple outputs with the window at different places for me.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to compute the sliding window variance (or standard deviation) using Python/OpenCV/Skimage.

This approach makes use of the following form for computing the variance (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance):

```
Variance = mean of square of image - square of mean of image
```

However, since the variance will be outside the 8-bit range, we take the square root to form the standard deviation.

I also use the (local) mean filter from the Skimage rank filter module.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import rectangle
import skimage.filters as filters

# Variance = mean of square of image - square of mean of image
# See # see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance

# read the image
# convert to 16-bits grayscale since mean filter below is limited 
# to single channel 8 or 16-bits, not float
# and variance will be larger than 8-bit range
img = cv2.imread('lena.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).astype(np.uint16)

# compute square of image
img_sq = cv2.multiply(img, img)

# compute local mean in 5x5 rectangular region of each image
# note: python will give warning about slower performance when processing 16-bit images
region = rectangle(5,5)
mean_img = filters.rank.mean(img, selem=region)
mean_img_sq = filters.rank.mean(img_sq, selem=region)

# compute square of local mean of img
sq_mean_img = cv2.multiply(mean_img, mean_img)

# compute variance using float versions of images
var = cv2.add(mean_img_sq.astype(np.float32), -sq_mean_img.astype(np.float32))

# compute standard deviation and convert to 8-bit format
std = cv2.sqrt(var).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# save results
# multiply by 2 to make brighter as an example
cv2.imwrite('lena_std.png',2*std)

# show results
# multiply by 2 to make brighter as an example
cv2.imshow('std', 2*std)  
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Local Standard Deviation Image for 5x5 Sliding Window:

[image]

**ADDITION**

Here is a version that finds the bounding box for the maximum average variance for the bounding box size and draws it on the variance image (actually standard deviation).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import rectangle
import skimage.filters as filters

# Variance = mean of square of image - square of mean of image
# See # see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance

# set the bounding box size
bbox_size = 25

# read the image
# convert to 16-bits grayscale since mean filter below is limited 
# to single channel 8 or 16-bits, not float
# and variance will be larger than 8-bit range
img = cv2.imread('lena.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).astype(np.uint16)

# compute square of image
img_sq = cv2.multiply(img, img)

# compute local mean in bbox_size x bbox_size rectangular region of each image
# note: python will give warning about slower performance when processing 16-bit images
region = rectangle(bbox_size, bbox_size)
mean_img = filters.rank.mean(img, selem=region)
mean_img_sq = filters.rank.mean(img_sq, selem=region)

# compute square of local mean of img
sq_mean_img = cv2.multiply(mean_img, mean_img)

# compute variance using float versions of images
var = cv2.add(mean_img_sq.astype(np.float32), -sq_mean_img.astype(np.float32))

# compute standard deviation and convert to 8-bit format
std = cv2.sqrt(var).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# find bbox_size x bbox_size region with largest var (or std)
# get the moving window average at each pixel
std_ave = (cv2.sqrt(var)).astype(np.uint8)

# find the pixel x,y with the largest mean
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(std_ave)
x,y = max_loc
print("x:", x, "y:", y, "max:", max_val)

# draw rectangle for bounding box on copy of std image
result = std.copy()
result = cv2.merge([result, result, result])
cv2.rectangle(result, (x, y), (x+bbox_size, y+bbox_size), (0,0,255), 1)

# save results
# multiply by 2 to make brighter as an example
cv2.imwrite('lena_std.png',std)
cv2.imwrite('lena_std_bbox.png',result)

# show results
# multiply by 2 to make brighter as an example
cv2.imshow('std', std)  
cv2.imshow('result', result)  
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
x: 208 y: 67 max: 79.0
```

Resulting Bounding Box:

[image]

Comment: This is great, gave me some idea, thanks a lot. But I want to put a bounding box on the original image. Bounding box should be at the place where the variation amongst pixels is the most.

Comment: How do you measure that?  Do you want the single pixel that has the brightest area? Do you know how big you want the bounding box. Once could get the brightest average for all pixels within a sliding bounding box, if you have a size in mind.

Comment: Basically perform object detection but by rule based method. Here the rule is draw a bounding box where there is variation in pixels. Size should depend on the size of image and the area for variation in pixels. Does this help you understand better?

Comment: No, you must specify a unique size for the bounding box or define a specific mathematical rule that determines the size of the bounding box. Different size bounding boxes will identify different size regions. You would have to test every size bounding box to find the one that has the minimum average variance (or standard deviation). The size of the window used to produce the variance also matters.

Comment: That's what I meant, define a mathematical rule that determines the size of the bounding box. How do I do this whole task? Can you please help?

Comment: I have no mathematical rule. My best suggestion is try for every box size and get the average value in the box. Then find the box that has the largest value. You can do a binary search to speed that up - small size, large size and one in between. Then try one half way between, Pick the best of the two. Continue that process.

Comment: Another thought would be to threshold the variance image. Then use distance transform to find the largest black area. That might define a limit on the box size you need. However, that is a completely untested idea.

Comment: I understand the concept but idk how to implement it. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I posted an addition to at least show you how to find the max variance  bounding box for a given size

Comment: Try inverting the std image. Threshold it. Then get the distance transform. Then find the largest distanced. Use that as the bounding box centered at the coordinates that have the largest distance.

Comment: You can also define a tolerance to the amount of detail or variance and trim to that amount. See my Imagemagick scripts, smartcrop an smarttrim at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick. smartcrop specifies a size window and smarttrim uses tolerance.

Comment: I tried a different approach and it worked but I'm facing an issue with my script if you don't mind looking I can add it. Lmk. Thanks!

Comment: OK. But you might post a new question

Comment: Okay, I posted a new question.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method to compute the windowed/rolling variance in regions of `WxH` is to use just `numpy` and `scipy` with convolutions, which are computed fairly quickly. An example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
# Create image data
original = np.zeros((811,123))
img = original + np.random.normal(0, 1, original.shape)
# Create averaging kernel
H, W = 5, 5
mean_op = np.ones((H,W))/(H*W)
# Carry out convolution to compute mean of square, and square of mean
mean_of_sq = scipy.signal.convolve2d( img**2, mean_op, mode='same', boundary='symm')
sq_of_mean = scipy.signal.convolve2d( img   , mean_op, mode='same', boundary='symm') **2
win_var    = mean_of_sq - sq_of_mean
```