# Trying to blur highest variance point of an image but some conversion problem exist in code

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, signal-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to **blur of highest variance point from the image**. I wrote code below. 1st part finds the variance of the image. I checked the resultant variance of an image and it is correct. (I used Lena's image) In 2nd part, I find the highest variance coordinates and send to this Function which finds gaussian blur. When I execute this code, it throws  `"C:\Tmp\blur_highest_variance.py", line 66, in sigma=15) numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'subtract' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('uint8') with casting rule 'same_kind'`
I tried a few conversions between types but no avail. Can you show me some direction?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt    
from skimage import measure
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
import math
import cv2
from skimage.morphology import rectangle
import skimage.filters as filters

######################Calculate Variance#######################
# Variance = mean of square of image - square of mean of image
# See # see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance

# read the image
# convert to 16-bits grayscale since mean filter below is limited 
# to single channel 8 or 16-bits, not float
# and variance will be larger than 8-bit range
img = cv2.imread(r".\lena_std512_512.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).astype(np.uint16)

# compute square of image
img_sq = cv2.multiply(img, img)

# compute local mean in 5x5 rectangular region of each image
# note: python will give warning about slower performance when processing 16-bit images
region = rectangle(10,10)
mean_img = filters.rank.mean(img, selem=region)
mean_img_sq = filters.rank.mean(img_sq, selem=region)

# compute square of local mean of img
sq_mean_img = cv2.multiply(mean_img, mean_img)

# compute variance using float versions of images
var = cv2.add(mean_img_sq.astype(np.float32), -sq_mean_img.astype(np.float32))

# compute standard deviation and convert to 8-bit format
std = cv2.sqrt(var).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# multiply by 2 to make brighter as an example
cv2.imwrite('lena_std_local_variance.jpg',std)    

#################Gaussian Blur Function###############
def gaussian_mask(x, y, shape, amp=1, sigma=15):
    """
    Returns an array of shape, with values based on

    amp * exp(-((i-x)**2 +(j-y)**2) / (2 * sigma ** 2))

    :param x: float
    :param y: float
    :param shape: tuple
    :param amp: float
    :param sigma: float
    :return: array
    """
    xv, yv = np.meshgrid(np.arange(shape[1]), np.arange(shape[0]))
    g = amp * np.exp(-((xv - x) ** 2 + (yv - y) ** 2) / (2 * sigma ** 2))
    return g

#################Find Gaussian Blur and Subtract###############

y, x = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(std), std.shape)       

std -= gaussian_mask(x, y,
                    shape=std.shape[:2],
                    amp=1,
                    sigma=15)

cv2.imwrite(r'.\gaussian\lena_std_local_variance.jpg',std)
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error message with its stack trace. It it easier to discover what the problem is if we know in what line of your code it happens.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Tmp\blur_highest_variance.py", line 66, in sigma=15)
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'subtract' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('uint8') with casting rule 'same_kind' @cris-luengo

Comment: Most of that stack trace disappeared. Please [edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: Thanks to @Rotem error disappeared but I don't get blurred portion on that specific coordinate still. Can you comment on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells us the line and the reason for the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Tmp\blur_highest_variance.py", line 66, in  sigma=15)
> numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'subtract' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('uint8') with casting rule 'same_kind'

It is more simple to debug the code using intermediate variables:
For example, use an intermediate named `gmask`:

```
gmask = gaussian_mask(x, y,
                      shape=std.shape[:2],
                      amp=1,
                      sigma=15)

print('gmask.dtype = ' + str(gmask.dtype))  # gmask.dtype = float64
print('std.dtype = ' + str(std.dtype))  # std.dtype = uint8
```

We don't really need to print the `dtype`, we may use the debugger, but printing demonstrates the reason for the error.
We can't subtract `float64` array from `uint8` using `-=` operator!

Using `std = std - gmask`, is not an error, but the type of the result is `float64`.

---

Suggested solution:

Cast `gmask` to `uint8` and use `cv2.subtract`:

```
gmask = gaussian_mask(x, y,
                      shape=std.shape[:2],
                      amp=1,
                      sigma=15)

std = cv2.subtract(std, gmask.clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8))
```

Using `cv2.subtract` is a safe way for subtracting two `uint8` matrices, because it clips the result to [0, 255] (includes overflow protection).

---

Result (`lena_std_local_variance.jpg`):
[image]

Comment: thank you so much. It is working great as intended by your code. One more question though do you know why the resultant image is not blurred at point [418 124]? This point is the result of y, x = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(std), std.shape)  so this point is the highest variance point. I should blur the image around that point with gaussian_mask function . But when I checked the image after gmasking at that specific coordinate, image is the same as you posted above. It seems it doesn't work. Isn't it?

Comment: for reference: I took some of the code from this link. @Rotem https://stackoverflow.com/a/66978299/1939432

Comment: I mean when I subtract the gaussian blurred part from the original image like we did in the code,  I should see some change in the resultant image isn't it? I fiddled with gaussian parameters a bit amp=5,  sigma=30 but I did not see any change on picture. What I should see according to theory is, the area around that coordinate should be much more blurry than surroundings. @Rotem

Comment: I don't know... just follow the math. It could be because you are clipping the result: `cv2.sqrt(var).clip(0,255)`. There must be a mathematical explanation. What development environment  are you using? It's not so difficult to check the result of specific coordinate using the debugger.

Comment: I am using Spyder.

Comment: In Spyder you can type the expression you want to evaluate in the command window. (I prefer PyCharm). You can execute your code step by step using Spyder, and check the values wherever you want.

Comment: I changed the amp to 60. It is seen on the picture now. Amplitude was not enough. Solved.